# Google In app purchase (consumable) listener is not working

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have an issue that is Payment is successful but addSubscriptionListener and addPurchaseListener not call

I am using this library:-
implementation  `'com.github.akshaaatt:Google-IAP:1.2.5'`

From this link:-
https://github.com/akshaaatt/Google-IAP

Here the listener is working after clicking twice on item to purchase.

Here is the listener:-

```
 iapConnector.addPurchaseListener(object : PurchaseServiceListener {
            override fun onPricesUpdated(iapKeyPrices: Map<String, DataWrappers.SkuDetails>) {
                // list of available products will be received here, so you can update UI with prices if needed
            }

            override fun onProductPurchased(purchaseInfo: DataWrappers.PurchaseInfo) {
               // will be triggered whenever purchase succeeded
            }

            override fun onProductRestored(purchaseInfo: DataWrappers.PurchaseInfo) {
                // will be triggered fetching owned products using IapConnector
            }
        })

 iapConnector.addSubscriptionListener(object : SubscriptionServiceListener {
            override fun onSubscriptionRestored(purchaseInfo: DataWrappers.PurchaseInfo) {
                // will be triggered upon fetching owned subscription upon initialization
            }

            override fun onSubscriptionPurchased(purchaseInfo: DataWrappers.PurchaseInfo) {
                // will be triggered whenever subscription succeeded
            }

            override fun onPricesUpdated(iapKeyPrices: Map<String, DataWrappers.SkuDetails>) {
                // list of available products will be received here, so you can update UI with prices if needed
            }
        })
```

I have put in the button click listener but still it is not called at once.